# Python Lambda function access cognito "sub" uuid

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a Lambda function written in python that is triggered by the API Gateway with proxy integration and a Cognito user pool authorizer. I am trying to access the "sub" UUID that Cognito gives every user, but nothing I try works. I have just about exhausted google of all related search results and nothing that I have found seems valid. They either return a null or they crash. My function (with every attempted UUID access line commented out) is below:

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #UniqueUser = context.identity.cognito_identity_id
    #UniqueUser = context.authorizer.claims.sub
    #UniqueUser = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub
    #UniqueUser = event.request.userAttributes.sub
    #UniqueUser = event.queryStringParameters.sub
    
    try:
        # Something that gets sub from cognito
    except:
        UniqueUser = "not valid code"
        
    if not UniqueUser:
        UniqueUser = "UniqueUser is null"
        
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda ' + UniqueUser + "!")
    };
```

Does anyone know any possible sources of this behavior or solution to this problem?

Comment: When I do this: ```print(vars(context))```          I get this returned as part of it: ```'client_context': None, 'identity': <bootstrap.CognitoIdentity object at 0x7fd269d02a50> ```        So, the client context is null and there is an identity key I can't seem to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the UUID of a Cognito user who is calling a Lambda function through the API Gateway with proxy integration, use the code below.

```py
UniqueUser = event['requestContext']['authorizer']['claims']['sub']
```